# Change table primary key into auto-incremented primary key

Tags: ms-access, primary-key, auto-increment, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to change a primary key into an autoincremented primary key in an Access table.

I'm trying to do as Remou said in a similar post,  editing the table and adding an autoincrement type field.

[image]

But when I try to do so I get a "property cannot be modified in linked tables" error and I cannot save the changes.

How can I change that primary key into an autoincremented primary key?

Comment: it sounds like the table you are trying to edit is linked from another source - you will need to change the table where it is actually stored, not the linked version - or you will need to make a local copy in your own data base that you can edit.

Comment: I believe another approach to this is creating a new table with an auto-increment column and copying (appending) the data to the new table.